# Faster R-CNN Model with Very Small Images Dataset

Tags: image-processing, conv-neural-network

hello i have 273 grayscale images from Drone and I would Like to detect Homes and Trees into the Images using Faster R-CNN method, But Due to My Small Dataset I Know that My model can not Train sufficiently, Please Guide Me and recommend a good Solution for My Problem

Answer (score 0):

There are many methods for augmentation. Augmentation indicate a way to increase number of images. For example, you can crop a lot of part of your image and save them as a new images. but remember when you do that you have to update your bounding box coordinates.